# Booting computer without graphics card

Tags: boot, graphics-card, motherboard, bios

As a little hobby project I want to build a pfSense router with some scrap I found and some parts I bought on eBay.

The motherboard is a MS-7728 Ver 2.0. The problem is that the motherboard only have one full length PCI express slot and two short slots. The two short slots are basically useless as neither the NIC or the graphics card can fit.

The system boots fine with OS and graphics card. However if I run the system with only motherboard, PSU, CPU and RAM, it doesn't seem to boot. It makes a long beep sound and then two shorts. It keeps repeating like that.

Why doesn't my system boot properly without a graphics card, and is there any way I can fix it?

Comment: Some systems are configured not to boot when they do not detect a graphics card or a keyboard. This is often configured in the BIOS. If possible add a graphics card, boot and check those settings.

Comment: Ah, and FYI: The two short slots are PCI-e x1 connectors. Electrically they will happily work with a NIC or a graphics card, though sometimes you need to open up one end of a slot.  Sadly that does not help much given the heat sink behind them.

Comment: ... and you might be able to change whether the system requires the graphics card in the BIOS... you would need to look up the motherboard manual if this can be done.

Comment: @Hennes Actually the heat sink wouldn't be too much of a problem(NIC is x2) if I decided to saw the end of the slot off, however I it would result in less bandwidth for the NIC and higher power consumption due the graphics card.

Comment: Yes, it would limit the NIC to PCI-e x1, so max 5.0Gbit bandwidth to the NIC. More than enough for a gigabit card, but lacking in for 10Gbit and beyond.  Which NICs are you using?

Comment: IBM Intel EXPI9404PTL Pro/1000 PT Quad Port. But still it is much preferred if there's a way I can avoid the GPU.

Comment: @BigChris Do you have any idea what these settings could be named? I have browsed the BIOS settings, but there doesn't seem to be any graphics card related settings.

Comment: A quick look and you're motherboard doesn't have an integrated graphics card and because the motherboard will have been designed as a standard desktop the manufacturer will have omitted any graphics card options in the BIOS and made sure you require a graphics card because you need to have some output with it being a desktop board. If you want truly headless then you will need to look for a motherboard that provides this...

Comment: @BigChris Do you know if it would be possible to perform some sort of BIOS hack?

Comment: You would need to flash the BIOS but you'd need to find a BIOS file for the motherboard and right version... in short, you're trying to do something with the wrong equipment and should get the right kit or accept you need a graphics card in this machine.